# Does perception affect damage done to deathclaws?

Tags: fallout-shelter

The advice I've seen with regards to deathclaw defense is that endurance and weapon damage are the items that matter.  I have never seen anyone explicitly say that perception does not affect damage however.

Comment: I'm skeptical that endurance matters. The only factors I've seen that make a difference are HP and weapon damage.

Comment: Endurance matters only during lvl up. You gain bonus HP the higher your end is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested a room with +5 to each special and the results were the same.

It does not matter which special is maxed, only weapon damage and HP matter.